# Best UX to Indicate To User That They Can Submit Multiple Times

Tags: forms, submit

I have a basic form template as follows:

[image]

The user enters data and then saves the data. The user potentially has a number of these submissions to make.

What is the best way to indicate to the user that they can add another entry?

Should the button be renamed to "Save and add another" or do I redirect them away from this page and to their dashboard (which is where they came from in the first place) where there is a link to "Add another entry". Clicking on that link brings them to this form again, so in effect they are going back and forth from the dashboard to this form if they have a number of submissions to make.

What design would involve least effort for the user and also most intuitive for the user?

Thanks.

Comment: after save prompt a message add another YES NO

Answer (score 3):

## Is this an application users spend a lot of time in? You can be explicit, or offer shortcuts, depending on your user base and their skill level.

#### A. Being explicit

In this case, you can give users two submission actions. The user still may have a split second pause while looking at the buttons, but they see all choices:

[image]

#### B. Power users and frequent actions

If you have an application, where users spend a good amount of time such as:

- document creation and editing (Word)
- content creation (Adobe)
- chat apps (Slack)

In this case users may be used to doing lots of repetitive actions, so it's possible to introduce shortcuts. I'm using the Shift key here as a straw man (there are other options).

One possibility is to introduce shortcuts with some persistent helper text. It's present, but attempts to stay out of the users way so as not to disrupt the task:

[image]

I know the wording of the helper text isn't ideal (does Shift alone make it save?), but the key is to give some feedback as a shortcut key is invoked.

I don't know your domain and its constraints, but if it's possible, you can test both options and see if users can complete their tasks.

Comment: That's given me an idea. I could have a checkbox next to the save button with some helper text indicating that if the user wants to add another entry they should check the checkbox and then click save. The application will keep presenting them with a new form. When they have finished, they can click the cancel button which will redirect back to their dashboard or if they uncheck the checkbox on their last save/submission it will also redirect them back to their dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Why press Save at all? Let it be submitted and saved automatically after some small delay. Google Documents and MS Office 360 do this.

Just tell the user that everything is already saved.

Comment: That's not really the use case here.   For this question, the OP has a specific form that can be filled in multiple times.  The question is about how the user signals that they are done with the form, allowing them to move on, either to something else, or to the next instance of the form.